# background header image css not sizing properly

Tags: html, css

I have added a background image to my header and it looks great at smaller size but I lose the full image at larger size. here is the code I have so far

```
.fusion-top-header .fusion-header {
  background-image: url("http://127.0.0.1/OTG/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/sunset_background.jpg")!important;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: none;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

I want all screen size to have the image look like what it is in the small screen one. I have the logo and menu moving and adjusting for screen size just not the image

Any help would be great.

Thanks

[image: Small screen]

[image: Large screen]

Answer (score 0):

Problem is this:

When you enlarge your screen height of your element .fusion-header remains the same. Since background-size is cover your image is trying to be full width, hence automatically gaining height.

You have option to set background-size to contain and background-position center, or you have option to adjust your .fusion-header height via vw/vh units.

As far as I know I can' t say that there is anything else.